# Filter non-blocking stream Webclient

Tags: java, json, spring, filter, spring-webflux

I'm dealing with WebFlux.
it's totally brandly new aspect for me as a reactive programming so i need a help with non-blocking Flux stream. I use Webclient(as consumer) to get constant stream, the problem is that i have to get just Json data, however stream contains not with just what i need and i have to filter the stream somehow, i get each string dynamically and for now filter all data that starts with "{" what means that json starts but if json  spread on not just the only one string and looks like that:

{

key: value

}

the error occurs

if it's spread just on one string like that: {key:value} everything works the way it supposed to be

My code example:

```
 try {
            server.getWebClient()
                    .post()
                    .uri(URL)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(server.prepareBodyRequestFilter()))
                    .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, err ->
                            Mono.error(new RuntimeException("The problem occured with status: " + err.statusCode())))
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                            err -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Server is not responding with status: " + err.statusCode())))
                    .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                    .subscribe(str -> {
                        System.out.println("Each string:" + str);
                    });
 } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage() + " " + e.getCause());

        }
```

If anybody knows how to filter unneeded data from the stream that's would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to stream data from the server

- Server-sent events pushing individual events (media type: `text/event-stream`)
- Streaming events separated by newlines (media type: `application/x-ndjson`)

You could deserialize json entry `DataEntry` and the `filter`

For example for `application/x-ndjson`

```
webclient.get()
   .uri(URL)
   .accept(APPLICATION_NDJSON)
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToFlux(DataEntry.class)
   .filter(entry -> entry.getIndex() % 2 == 0);
```

for SSE just set `.accept(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)`

**UPDATE**

For "classic" json array response. Not sure what exactly you want to filter out but, `bodyToFlux` should handle it if json is valid. Here is a complete test using wiremock

```
@Test
void test() {
    String data = """
            [
            {
            "key": "key1"
            },
            {
            "key": "key2"
            },
            {
            "key": "key3"
            }
            ]
            """;

    stubFor(get("/test")
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withBody(data)
            )
    );

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:" + wireMockServer.port());

    Flux<DataEntry> res = webClient.get()
            .uri("/test")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataEntry.class);

    StepVerifier.create(res)
            .expectNext(new DataEntry("key1"))
            .expectNext(new DataEntry("key2"))
            .expectNext(new DataEntry("key3"))
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

ps

you don't need to apply `try-catch` to reactive sequence and typically you don't need to `subscribe` explicitly

Comment: I don't stream data as i'm dealing with the client side, i just retrieve it the way it is so i just need to get only json ignoring the rest and work with POJO then

Comment: Not sure what is the server response but pls check the updated answer with the complete test